# Can I sit for “Kabbolas Shabbos” within 4 amos of someone saying the mincha Amidah?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, standing-sitting, kabbalat-shabbat

Tefillo Kehilchoso (ch. 11, fn. 284) and Shulchan Oruch ([102:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=258)) quote [Tosephos Brochos 31b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=31b&format=pdf) to say that one may sit beside someone praying the amidah if one is involved in prayer activity. He asserts that this includes even “aizehu mekomon” (part of the sacrifices section of morning prayers), “borchi nafshi” and “pirkei ovos” (said by some after the afternoon Shabbos service).

Can the “Kabbolas Shabbos” service [composed by 16th century Kabbalists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_prayer) beginning with “Lechu neran’no” be considered the same as “aizehu mekomon” etc.?

Comment: What makes you think that Kabbolas Shabbos is not considered prayer?

Comment: @yoel See this [Revach article](http://matzav.com/why-does-the-chazan-stand-at-the-bima-for-kabbolas-shabbos) who says, "originally there was no such Tefila as Kabalas Shabbos";              "At first only Yichidei Segula said Kabalas Shabbos, privately in their own homes."                and "When the crowds became very large the people did not want to leave the main Shul so they said it in Shul but they had the Chazan stand in an untraditional place to differentiate it from the main Tefila."

Answer (score 1):

The Piskei Tshuvos siman 102:2 explains that tehilliem and other prayers which are not part of the order of the tefillah the heter does not apply.Kappolos Shabbas I believe is considered part of the seder hatiffilah nowadays al pi savarah. He brings listening to chazaras hasatz and krias HaTorah count and tehillim which is said everyday. See it inside for yourself and see footnotes 28,29,and 30.

Comment: The *תפילה כהלכתה* (ch. 11, § 124, fn. 284) interprets the *Mishnah B'rurah* (102:7) as saying that just listening to *chazaras hashas*, etc., is not enough to permit a person to sit down next to someone who is reciting the *sh'moneh esrei*.

Comment: look up the Piskei Tshuvos.